# Find record of one type with more than one associated HABTM type

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0, model-associations

I have two models in my CakePHP application: `NewsArticle` and `Image`. `Image` is associated with `NewsArticle` using a HABTM (has and belongs to many) association, so authors can build up a gallery for an article if they wish.

On my application’s homepage I want to display the top story, which will simply be the latest published article with at least one associated image. How would I form this condition in my controller? So far, I have:

```
<?php
$topStory = $this->NewsArticle->find('first', array(
    'order' => array(
        'NewsArticle.created' => 'desc'
    )
));
```

But I am unsure how to “count” the number of `Image` records attached to my `NewsArticle` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use HABTM, you'll need to do a JOIN (see [CakePHP Joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)).

The reason is, normal `find()`s actually do separate queries, then CakePHP puts the data together before it returns it to you.  If you're trying to limit the main results by the existence of sub-results, you'll need to use a JOIN.

If you're able to get away with HasMany instead (meaning an `Image` would `belongTo` a `NewsArticle`), you can use [CakePHP's counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count).

Comment: Thanks. I probably wouldn’t get away with a `hasMany` relation in case I want an image to be used in multiple articles if I were to say, introduce an image library for authors in the future.

Comment: Helps if I RTFM! Read the section in the CakePHP cookbook on joins and ended up arriving at this solution: https://gist.github.com/4401761. Thanks for pointing me towards joins.

Answer (score 0):

It's often wise to create a CakePHP model for the HABTM join table, then you can query that table.

NewsArticle would have a table named news_articles. Image would have a table named images. So the join table is likely news_articles_images.

I recommend you create model with an alias name that is different from the join table. To prevent problems. So you could do something like this.

```
class Gallery extends AppModel
{
     var $name = 'Gallery';
     var $useTable = 'news_articles_images';
     var $belongsTo = array('NewsArticle','Image');
}
```

Then in your controller you can easily find the first article that has an image.

```
$topStory = $this->Gallery->find('first',array('order'=>array('NewsArticle.created'=>'DESC'));
```

Comment: You mention creating a new model that’s actually an alias of the join. Does CakePHP create a “bridge” model internally and if so, could I actually query *that* pseudo-model instead of creating my own?

Comment: @MartinBean yes it does create one internally. It's name will be the name of the join table, but it won't have any $belongsTo association configured. Also, I don't recommend creating a Model.php file with the same name as this internal one. Cake will not always use the one you created.

Comment: To get an instance of the internal model - CakeRegistry::init('NewsArticlesImages'); or something based upon the join table name.

Comment: This is called "hasMany Through" and is in the Cake Book.

Comment: @Dave hasMany would require the other table contains alias_id column. BelongsTo requires that the current table contains an alias_id. Which is correct for a join table.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - I was not arguing with you - I was just informing you that what you were describing (creating a model for the HABTM table) is called "hasMany through" and is described in detail in the CakePHP book under the "Associations" area.

Comment: @Dave oh. lol. Sorry about that. I was up until 4am last night. Feeling a little tired and grumpy. I've never heard of the turn "hasMany through" before. Thanks.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - we've all been there, no big deal :)   I'm not sure if it's a CakePHP-specific term or not, but - here's the link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model